# Duda con errores reportados con Valgrind

Tags: c++

Estoy aprendiendo a usar Valgrind para detectar errores en mi programa. Me he encontrado con un error de pérdida de memoria. Este es el código:

Clase ***nodo***

```
#ifndef NODO_H_INCLUDED
#define NODO_H_INCLUDED

#include <iostream>

template <typename DATOA, typename DATON>
struct arista;//declaración previa

template <typename DATON, typename DATOA>
struct nodo
{
    DATON datonodo;
    unsigned short int nPadres;
    nodo<DATON,DATOA>* siguiente;
    arista<DATOA,DATON>* adyacente;
    //constructor
    nodo (DATON N=0, unsigned short int numPadres=0, nodo<DATON,DATOA>* s=nullptr, arista<DATOA, DATON>* a=nullptr):datonodo(N),nPadres(numPadres),siguiente(s),adyacente(a) {}
    //constructor copia
    nodo (const nodo<DATON,DATOA>& n)
    {
        std::cout<<"nodo Constructor copia"<<std::endl;
        datonodo=n.datonodo;
        nPadres=n.nPadres;
        siguiente=nullptr;
        adyacente=nullptr;            
    }
    //destructor
    ~nodo()
    {
        siguiente=nullptr;
        adyacente=nullptr;
        //borrar pila?
        //borrar datonodo?            
    }
    //operador de asignacion
    nodo& operator = (const nodo<DATON, DATOA>& n)
    {
        if (this!=&n)
        {
            datonodo=n.datonodo;
            nPadres=n.nPadres;
            siguiente=nullptr;
            adyacente=nullptr;
        }
        return *this;
    }
};

#endif // NODO_H_INCLUDED
```

Clase ***arista***

```
#ifndef ARISTA_H_INCLUDED
#define ARISTA_H_INCLUDED

template <typename, typename>
struct nodo;

template <typename DATOA, typename DATON>
struct arista
{
    DATOA datoarista;
    nodo<DATON,DATOA>* destino;
    nodo<DATON,DATOA>* origen;
    arista<DATOA,DATON>* siguiente;
    arista<DATOA,DATON>* anterior;
    //constructores
    arista(DATOA A=0, nodo<DATON,DATOA>* d=nullptr, nodo<DATON,DATOA>* o=nullptr,
           arista<DATOA,DATON>* s=nullptr, arista<DATOA,DATON>* an=nullptr):datoarista(A),destino(d),origen(o),
           siguiente(s), anterior(an) {}

    arista (const arista<DATOA,DATON>& a)
    {
        datoarista=a.datoarista;
        destino=nullptr;
        origen=nullptr;
        siguiente=nullptr;
        anterior=nullptr;
    }
    //operador de asignacion
    arista& operator = (const arista<DATOA, DATON>& a)
    {
        if (this!=&a)
            {
                datoarista=a.datoarista;
                destino=nullptr;
                origen=nullptr;
                siguiente=nullptr;
                anterior=nullptr;
            }
        return *this;
    }

    ~arista()
    {
        //std::cout<<"Destructor arista"<<std::endl;
    }
};

#endif // ARISTA_H_INCLUDED
```

Clase ***grafo***

```
#ifndef GRAFO_H
#define GRAFO_H

#include <iostream>
#include <stack>
#include <list>

#include "arista.h"
#include "nodo.h"

template <typename DATON, typename DATOA>
class Grafo
{
    typedef DATON datonodo_t;
    typedef DATOA datoarista_t;
    typedef nodo<datonodo_t,datoarista_t>* pNodo;
    typedef arista<datoarista_t,datonodo_t>* pArista;
    typedef nodo<datonodo_t,datoarista_t> t_nodo;
    typedef arista<datoarista_t,datonodo_t> t_arista;


public:
    //constructor
    Grafo():Raiz(nullptr),nNodos(0)
    {
        std::cout<<"Constructor grafo"<<std::endl;
    }
    Grafo (pNodo nodo)
    {
        //Raiz = new t_nodo(*nodo);
        Raiz = nodo;
        nNodos=1;
    }
    Grafo (datonodo_t nodo)
    {
        Raiz = new t_nodo(nodo);
    }
    //constructor copia
    Grafo (const Grafo& G);
    //funciones
    /************auxiliares de nodos y aristas***************/
    void anadirNodo (pNodo& n);
    void eliminarNodo(pNodo& n);
    //void anadirArista (pNodo& NodoOrigen, pNodo& NodoDestino, pArista& precedente, pArista& NuevaArista);
    void eliminarArista (pArista& A);
    pArista hallarArista (pNodo& nodopadre, pNodo& nodohijo);
    /*********insertar,eliminar,copiar elementos del grafo*******************/
    void Insertar (pNodo& padre, pNodo& hijo, pArista& NuevaArista, int posicion=-1);
    void borrarNodos(pArista& A);
    void Copiar(pNodo& padre, pNodo& hijo, pArista NuevaArista, pArista precedente=nullptr);
    pNodo CrearGrafoAPartirDeNodo(const pNodo& nodo);
    /******funciones para recorrer el grafo*************************/
    std::list<pNodo> recorrerNodos() const;
    std::list<pNodo>& recorrerGrafo(const pNodo& inicio);
    std::list<pNodo>& lista_recorrerGrafo(const pNodo& inicio);
    /**********comprobaciones necesarias****************/
    bool esReferenciaCircular(pNodo& padre, pNodo& hijo);
    bool existeHermano (pNodo& padre, pNodo& hijo);
    bool existeNodo (const pNodo& n);
    /***********otras*******************************/
    void guardaAristas (const pNodo& n);
    void guardaAristasParaCopia (const pNodo& n);
    pNodo posicionarseEnNodo(const datonodo_t& dato);
    template <typename T>
    void VaciarPila(std::stack<T>& pila);
    /***********consultoras*************************/
    const pNodo& LeeRaiz() const
    {
        return Raiz;
    }
    ~Grafo();

private:

    pNodo Raiz;
    int nNodos;
    std::stack<pArista> pilaAristas;
    std::stack<pArista> pilaAristasParaCopia;
    std::stack<pNodo> pilaNodos;
    std::list<pNodo>nodos;
    std::stack<std::pair<pArista,int> >aristasConNiveles;
    std::list<std::pair<pNodo,int> >nodosConNiveles;
    //funciones privadas porque son de uso interno
    void InsertarHijo(pNodo& padre, pNodo& hijo, pArista& NuevaArista, pArista& precedente=nullptr);
    void InsertarHijo(pNodo& padre, pNodo& hijo, datoarista_t valorArista, pArista precedente=nullptr);
};

//********************//
//destructor del grafo//
//********************//
template <typename datonodo_t, typename datoarista_t>
Grafo<datonodo_t,datoarista_t>::~Grafo()
{
    std::cout<<"Iniciamos el destructor"<<std::endl;
    //borro la pila de aristas antes de usarla.
    VaciarPila(pilaAristas);
    pArista A;
    //meto todas las arista del nodo Raiz en la pila
    guardaAristas(Raiz);
    //empiezo a borrar todas las ramas que hay en la pila
    while (!pilaAristas.empty())
    {
        A=pilaAristas.top();
        pilaAristas.pop();
        borrarNodos(A);
    }
    delete Raiz;
    std::cout<<"Borrada la raiz"<<std::endl;
}

//*****************//
//constructor copia//
//*****************//
template <typename datonodo_t, typename datoarista_t>
Grafo<datonodo_t, datoarista_t>::Grafo (const Grafo<datonodo_t, datoarista_t>& G)
{
    std::cout<<"CONSTRUCTOR COPIA"<<std::endl;
    Raiz = CrearGrafoAPartirDeNodo(G.Raiz);
    std::cout<<"Copia terminada"<<std::endl;
}

//**************//
//añadir un nodo//
//**************//
template <typename datonodo_t, typename datoarista_t>
void Grafo<datonodo_t,datoarista_t>::anadirNodo(pNodo& n)
{
    if (Raiz==nullptr)
    {
        Raiz=n;
    }
    else
    {
        pNodo indice=Raiz;
        //me posiciono al final de la lista
        while (indice && indice->siguiente!=0)
        {
            indice=indice->siguiente;
        }
        indice->siguiente=n;
    }
    nNodos++;
}

//****************//
//eliminar un nodo//
//****************//
template <typename datonodo_t, typename datoarista_t>
void Grafo<datonodo_t,datoarista_t>::eliminarNodo(pNodo& n)
{
    pNodo anterior=Raiz;
    //avanzo anterior hasta el nodo anterior al que quiero borrar
    while (anterior->siguiente!=n)
    {
        anterior=anterior->siguiente;
    }
    if (anterior==Raiz)//primer elemento
    {
        Raiz->siguiente=n->siguiente;
    }
    else
    {
        anterior->siguiente=n->siguiente;
    }
    delete n;
    nNodos--;
}

//*******************//
//eliminar una arista//
//*******************//
template <typename datonodo_t, typename datoarista_t>
void Grafo<datonodo_t,datoarista_t>::eliminarArista(pArista& A)
{
    pArista aux = A;
    pNodo indice=Raiz;
    //veo si la arista a borrar es la adyacente de algún nodo (primera arista)
    while (indice && indice->adyacente!=A)
    {
        indice=indice->siguiente;
    }
    if (indice)//si finalmente la arista a borrar es adyacente de indice
    {
        //si es arista única
        if (!A->anterior && !A->siguiente)
        {
            //std::cout<<"Es arista unica!!!"<<std::endl;
        }
        indice->adyacente = aux->siguiente;
    }
    if (aux->anterior)
    {
        aux->anterior->siguiente = aux->siguiente;
    }
    if (aux->siguiente)
    {
        aux->siguiente->anterior=aux->anterior;
    }
    delete aux;
}

//***********************************************//
//borrar todos los nodos que penden de una arista//
//***********************************************//

template <typename datonodo_t, typename datoarista_t>
void Grafo<datonodo_t,datoarista_t>::borrarNodos(pArista& A)
{
    pNodo hijo=A->destino;
    //quitar un padre al nodo hijo
    if (hijo->nPadres>0) hijo->nPadres--;
    //si todavía es hijo de algún padre....
    if (hijo->nPadres)
    {
        //...me limito a borrar la arista que une al padre con el hijo
        eliminarArista(A);
    }
    else //si se queda huerfanito
    {
        //si el hijo es hoja no tiene aristas que salgan de él, luego adyacente apunta a 0
        if (!hijo->adyacente)
        {
            //me posiciono en la arista a borrar
            eliminarArista(A);
            eliminarNodo(hijo);//lo saco de la lista general de nodos
        }
        else
        {
            guardaAristas(hijo);
            eliminarArista(A);
            eliminarNodo(hijo);
            while (!pilaAristas.empty())
            {
                A=pilaAristas.top();
                pilaAristas.pop();
                borrarNodos(A);
            }
        }
    }
}

/***********************/
/****Insertar nodo *****/
/***********************/

template <typename datonodo_t, typename datoarista_t>
void Grafo<datonodo_t,datoarista_t>::Insertar(pNodo& padre, pNodo& hijo, pArista& NuevaArista, int posicion)
{
    if (Raiz==nullptr)
    {
        Raiz = padre;
    }
    if (!existeNodo(padre))
    {
        anadirNodo(padre);
    }
    if (!existeNodo(hijo))
    {
        anadirNodo(hijo);
    }
    //inserto la arista
    if (!esReferenciaCircular(padre,hijo) && !existeHermano(padre,hijo))//comprobacion necesaria
    {
        hijo->nPadres++;//añado un padre
        NuevaArista->origen=padre;
        NuevaArista->destino=hijo;
        //caso 1. Primer nodo que cuelga del nodo padre
        if (!padre->adyacente)
        {
            padre->adyacente = NuevaArista;
        }
        else
        {
            //caso 2. Poner el nuevo nodo en primer lugar habiendo otros nodos existentes
            if (posicion==0)
            {
                NuevaArista->siguiente=padre->adyacente;
                padre->adyacente->anterior=NuevaArista;
                padre->adyacente=NuevaArista;
            }
            else//casos 3 y 4. El primer paso comun es situar la arista precedente a la que quiero insertar
            {
                pArista precedente = padre->adyacente;
                //caso 3. Si no se especifica posicion esta vale -1 y se inserta al final
                if (posicion<0)
                {
                    while(precedente && precedente->siguiente)
                    {
                        //std::cout<<"INSERTO AL FINALe"<<std::endl;
                        precedente=precedente->siguiente;
                    }
                }
                //caso 4. Me situo en la posicion dada
                else
                {
                    //std::cout<<"INSERTO POR POSICION"<<std::endl;
                    for (int i=0; i<posicion-1; i++)
                    {
                        precedente = precedente->siguiente;
                    }
                }
                //por ultimo ligo la nueva arista
                if (precedente && precedente->siguiente)
                {
                    precedente->siguiente->anterior=NuevaArista;
                }
                NuevaArista->siguiente=precedente->siguiente;
                NuevaArista->anterior=precedente;
                precedente->siguiente=NuevaArista;
            }
        }
    }
}

//**************************//
//insertar version con dato //
//**************************//

template <typename datonodo_t, typename datoarista_t>
void Grafo<datonodo_t,datoarista_t>::InsertarHijo(pNodo& padre, pNodo& hijo, datoarista_t valorArista, pArista precedente)
{
    pArista nueva = new t_arista(valorArista);
    InsertarHijo(padre, hijo, nueva, precedente);
}

//*******************************************//
//hallar la arista precedente a un nodo dado //
//*******************************************//

template <typename datonodo_t, typename datoarista_t>
arista<datoarista_t,datonodo_t>* Grafo<datonodo_t,datoarista_t>::hallarArista (pNodo& nodopadre, pNodo& nodohijo)
{
    pArista precedente = nullptr;
    if (nodopadre->adyacente)
    {
        precedente= nodopadre->adyacente;
        while(precedente->siguiente)
        {
            if (precedente->destino==nodohijo)
            {
                //std::cout<<"Retorno precedente"<<std::endl;
                return precedente;
            }
            else
            {
                precedente=precedente->siguiente;
            }
        }
    }
    std::cout<<"No retorno nada"<<std::endl;
    return precedente;
}

//**********************************************************************//
//copia un grafo a partir de un nodo dado en una parte del grafo actual //
//**********************************************************************//
template <typename datonodo_t, typename datoarista_t>
void Grafo<datonodo_t,datoarista_t>::Copiar(pNodo& padre, pNodo& hijo, pArista NuevaArista, pArista precedente)
{
    std::cout<<"FUNCION COPIAR "<<padre->datonodo<<"-->"<<hijo->datonodo<<std::endl;
    pArista copianuevaarista = nullptr;
    if (NuevaArista)
    {
        copianuevaarista = new t_arista(*NuevaArista);
    }
    else
    {
        copianuevaarista = new t_arista();
    }
    pNodo copiahijo = posicionarseEnNodo(hijo->datonodo);
    if (!copiahijo)
    {
        copiahijo = new t_nodo(*hijo);
        copiahijo->nPadres--;
    }
    guardaAristasParaCopia(hijo);
    pArista A = padre->adyacente;
    int pos=0;
    while (A && A!=precedente)
    {
        pos++;
        A=A->siguiente;
    }
    Insertar(padre,copiahijo,copianuevaarista,pos);
    while (!pilaAristasParaCopia.empty())
    {
        pArista actual = pilaAristasParaCopia.top();
        pNodo nieto = actual->destino;
        pilaAristasParaCopia.pop();
        std::cout<<"Copia hijo adyacente: "<<copiahijo->adyacente<<std::endl;
        pArista prec = hallarArista(copiahijo,nieto);
        pNodo repadre = posicionarseEnNodo(actual->origen->datonodo);
        if (repadre)
        {
            Copiar(repadre, nieto, actual,prec);
        }
    }
}

//********************************************//
//Crea un grafo a partir de un nodo dado      //
//********************************************//

template <typename datonodo_t, typename datoarista_t>
nodo<datonodo_t,datoarista_t>* Grafo<datonodo_t,datoarista_t>::CrearGrafoAPartirDeNodo(const pNodo& nodo)
{
    pNodo raiz = nullptr;
    if (nodo)
    {
        raiz =  new t_nodo(*nodo);
    }
    Raiz=raiz;//tengo que definir ya la raiz aqui aunque no tenga mucho sentido porque la necesito definida para otras funciones
    guardaAristasParaCopia(nodo);
    while (!pilaAristasParaCopia.empty())
    {
        pArista AristaHijo = pilaAristasParaCopia.top();
        pilaAristasParaCopia.pop();
        Copiar(raiz,AristaHijo->destino,AristaHijo,nodo->adyacente->anterior);
    }

    return raiz;
}

//******************************************//
//recorre toda la lista de nodos del grafo  //
//******************************************//

template <typename datonodo_t, typename datoarista_t>
std::list<nodo<datonodo_t,datoarista_t>*>Grafo<datonodo_t,datoarista_t>::recorrerNodos() const
{
    //nodos.clear();
    std::list<pNodo> nodos;
    if (Raiz)
    {
        pNodo indice = Raiz;
        nodos.push_back(indice);
        while (indice->siguiente)
        {
            indice= indice->siguiente;
            nodos.push_back(indice);
        }
    }
    return nodos;
}

//*************************************//
//recorrer el arbol a partir de un nodo//
//*************************************//

template <typename datonodo_t, typename datoarista_t>
std::list<nodo<datonodo_t,datoarista_t>*>& Grafo<datonodo_t,datoarista_t>::recorrerGrafo(const pNodo& inicio)
{
    VaciarPila(pilaAristas);
    nodos.clear();
    return lista_recorrerGrafo(inicio);
}

template <typename datonodo_t, typename datoarista_t>
std::list<nodo<datonodo_t,datoarista_t>*>& Grafo<datonodo_t,datoarista_t>::lista_recorrerGrafo(const pNodo& inicio)
{
    pArista A;
    if (inicio)
    {
        guardaAristas(inicio);
        while (!pilaAristas.empty())
        {
            A=pilaAristas.top();
            pilaAristas.pop();
            nodos.push_back(A->destino);
            lista_recorrerGrafo(A->destino);
        }
    }
    return nodos;
}

//*********************************************************************//
//busca si un nodo que quiero copiar como hijo de otro es padre de éste//
//necesario para evitar referencias circulares                         //
//*********************************************************************//

template <typename datonodo_t, typename datoarista_t>
bool Grafo<datonodo_t,datoarista_t>::esReferenciaCircular(pNodo& padre, pNodo& hijo)
{
    if (padre==hijo)
    {
        std::cout<<"Referencia $$ circular"<<std::endl;
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        pArista A;
        bool encontrado=false;
        guardaAristas(hijo);
        while (!pilaAristas.empty())
        {
            A=pilaAristas.top();
            pilaAristas.pop();
            if (A->destino==padre)
            {
                //vacio la pila
                while (!pilaAristas.empty())
                    pilaAristas.pop();
                std::cout<<"Referencia circular"<<std::endl;
                return true;
            }
            return encontrado || esReferenciaCircular(padre,A->destino);
        }
    }
    return false;
}

//*************************************************************//
//comprueba la existencia de un nodo igual al que quiero copiar//
//necesario para evitar tener dos nodos iguales colgando del   //
//mismo padre                                                  //
//*************************************************************//

template <typename datonodo_t, typename datoarista_t>
bool Grafo<datonodo_t,datoarista_t>::existeHermano (pNodo& padre, pNodo& hijo)
{
    pArista A=padre->adyacente;
    while (A!=nullptr)
    {
        //std::cout<<"posicionada la arista"<<A<<std::endl;
        if (A->destino==hijo)
        {
            return true;
        }
        A=A->siguiente;
    }
    return false;
}

//*********************************************//
//comprueba la presencia de un nodo en la lista//
//para evitar su inclusión por duplicado       //
//*********************************************//

template <typename datonodo_t, typename datoarista_t>
bool Grafo<datonodo_t,datoarista_t>::existeNodo (const pNodo& n)
{
    pNodo indice=Raiz;
    if (n==indice)
        return true;
    else
    {
        while (indice->siguiente)
        {
            indice=indice->siguiente;
            if (n==indice)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}

//***************************************************//
//guarda las aristas que penden de un nodo en la pila//
//***************************************************//

template <typename datonodo_t, typename datoarista_t>
void Grafo<datonodo_t,datoarista_t>::guardaAristas (const pNodo& n)
{
    pArista A;

    if (n && n->adyacente) //si hay aristas
    {
        A=n->adyacente;
        //me posiciono en la última arista
        while (A->siguiente!=nullptr)
        {
            A=A->siguiente;
        }
        //empiezo el recorrido hacia atrás
        while (A->anterior!=nullptr)
        {
            pilaAristas.push (A); //meto la arista en la pila
            A=A->anterior;
        }
        pilaAristas.push (A); //meto la primera arista en la pila*/
    }
}


template <typename datonodo_t, typename datoarista_t>
void Grafo<datonodo_t,datoarista_t>::guardaAristasParaCopia(const pNodo& n)
{
    pArista A;
    if (n && n->adyacente) //si hay aristas
    {
        A=n->adyacente;
        //me posiciono en la última arista
        while (A->siguiente!=nullptr)
        {
            A=A->siguiente;
        }
        while (A->anterior!=nullptr)
        {
            if (A->destino)
                pilaAristasParaCopia.push (A); //meto la arista en la pila
            A=A->anterior;
        }
        if (A->destino)
            pilaAristasParaCopia.push (A); //meto la arista en la pila
    }
}

//*******************************************************************************************************//
//si existe un nodo con el valor a comparar, devolvemos ese nodo. En caso concreto devolvemos valor nulo //
//*******************************************************************************************************//

template <typename DATON, typename DATOA>
nodo<DATON,DATOA>* Grafo<DATON,DATOA>::posicionarseEnNodo(const datonodo_t& dato)
{
    std::cout<<"Buscando el nodo con codigo: "<<dato<<std::endl;
    pNodo indice=Raiz;
    while (indice)// && indice->siguiente)
    {
        if (indice->datonodo == dato)
        {
            return indice;
        }
        indice=indice->siguiente;
    }
    return nullptr;
}

//*********************//
// vaciar la pila dada //
//*********************//

template <typename DATON, typename DATOA>
template <typename T>
void Grafo<DATON,DATOA>::VaciarPila(std::stack<T>& pila)
{
    while (!pila.empty())
    {
        pila.pop();
    }
}

#endif // GRAFO_H
```

Un ***main.cpp*** para manejarlo:

```
#include <list>
#include <iomanip>

#include "./grafo.h"

typedef char datonodo_t;
typedef int datoarista_t;

typedef nodo<datonodo_t,datoarista_t>* pNodo;
typedef arista<datoarista_t,datonodo_t>* pArista;
typedef nodo<datonodo_t,datoarista_t> t_nodo;
typedef arista<datoarista_t,datonodo_t> t_arista;

void verLista (std::list<pNodo>lista)
{
    for (auto it = lista.begin(); it!=lista.end(); ++it)
    {
        std::cout<<(*it)->datonodo;
    }
    std::cout<<std::endl;
}

void verLista(std::list<std::pair<pNodo,int>>lista)
{
    for (auto it=lista.begin(); it!=lista.end(); ++it)
    {
        std::cout<<std::setw((*it).second)<<"-"<<(*it).first->datonodo<<"-"<<&(*it)<<std::endl;
    }
    std::cout<<std::endl;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    pNodo A = new t_nodo('A');
    pNodo B = new t_nodo('B');
    pNodo C = new t_nodo('C');
    pNodo D = new t_nodo('D');
    pNodo E = new t_nodo('E');
    pNodo F = new t_nodo('F');
    pNodo G = new t_nodo('G');

    pArista AB = new t_arista(20);
    pArista AC = new t_arista(20);
    pArista AD = new t_arista(20);
    pArista BE = new t_arista(20);
    pArista BF = new t_arista(20);
    pArista BG = new t_arista(20);
    //pArista CG = new t_arista(20);

    Grafo<datonodo_t,datoarista_t>g(A);

    g.Insertar(A,B,AB);
    g.Insertar(A,C,AC);
    g.Insertar(A,D,AD,0);
    g.Insertar(B,E,BE);
    g.Insertar(B,F,BF);
    g.Insertar(B,G,BG);
    //g.Insertar(C,G,CG);


    std::cout<<"lista original: ";
    verLista(g.recorrerNodos());
    verLista(g.recorrerGrafo(g.LeeRaiz()));
    std::cout<<"Raiz: "<<g.LeeRaiz()->datonodo<<std::endl;
    Grafo<char,int>g1(g);
    std::cout<<"lista duplicada g1: ";
    verLista(g1.recorrerNodos());
    verLista(g1.recorrerGrafo(g1.LeeRaiz()));
    std::cout<<"Raiz g1: "<<g1.LeeRaiz()->datonodo<<std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Si el programa se ejecuta tal y como está ahora (Sin crear la arista CG ni insertarla), no hay errores de fuga de memoria, pero si descomento estas dos últimas líneas sí la hay. Cuando invoco al constructor copia del grafo, éste recorre el grafo original nodo por nodo. La idea -en la función `Copiar()` de la clase `Grafo` es que si en el grafo destino el nodo no existe, se cree y se ligue al grafo por medio de sus aristas, pero si ya existe, sólo se ligue. Es una implementación del método de lista de adyacencia.

Comment: Falta algo de contexto, dado que es una pregunta sobre pérdida de memoria es relevante saber cómo (y dónde) la liberas. Otra pregunta: ¿Qué sucede si cambias los punteros en crudo por punteros inteligentes?

Comment: Intenta presentar un ejemplo mínimo y completo que reproduzca el problema. Puede suceder, por ejemplo, que despues de abandonar la función ningún puntero apunte a la memoria que reservas con new y que por ahí se esté perdiendo la memoria

Comment: Voto para cerrar la pregunta ya que en prácticamente 24 horas no se ha editado la pregunta y con la información que tiene actualmente es imposible responderla

Comment: @eferion, estaba intentando reducir el código al mínimo borrando los métodos que no intervienen, pero sobrepaso los 30.000 caracteres y no me deja editar el mensaje. ¿Cómo puedo hacer para mostrar el código?

Comment: Elimina métodos y variables que no sean necesarios y no se utilicen... además, de las funciones que sean necesarias elimina todo el código supérfluo que no afecte al resultado de valgrind

Comment: @Paula_plus_plus , ya he editado el mensaje para que salga un código mínimo compilable y que reproduzca el error. A cambio he quitado los avisos de Valgrind porque me sobrepasaba el nº de caracteres necesarios. Por otro lado, la verdad es que nunca he usado punteros inteligentes. Supongo que debería empezar a mirarlos. Sobre el destructor, ya está la implementación. Básicamente llama a una función para borrar los nodos y esta se encarga de borrar las aristas.

Comment: @eferion, ya he conseguido publicar un código completo que reproduzca el error. Aunque he borrado todos los métodos que no intervienen, todavía hay otros tantos que sí lo hacen. Por otra parte, para no sobrepasar el nº de caracteres he sacrificado la salida de Valgrind

Comment: Tu código no compila... no puedes poner `nullptr` como valor por defecto de una referencia: `void Copiar(pNodo& padre, pNodo& hijo, pArista NuevaArista, pArista& precedente=nullptr);`

Comment: Tiene toda la lógica lo que dices, pero no sé por qué a mi no me da error. Este es el log: g++ -Wall -g -pedantic-errors -std=c++11  -c /ruta/GrafoTrozo/main.cpp -o obj/Debug/main.o
g++  -o bin/Debug/GrafoTrozo obj/Debug/main.o   
Output file is bin/Debug/GrafoTrozo with size 252.73 KB. No obstante voy a quitar el paso por referencia, puesto que no influye (creo en el resultado)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error se encuentra en la forma en la que se gestiona el destructor de la clase `Grafo`. El motivo es que en el momento de borrar uno de los nodos resulta que está asociado a varias aristas... por lo que no se destruye en esa pasada... y no se vuelve a pasar por el en el futuro. Puedes probar a depurar el código... es el nodo número 13 (por orden de construcción) el que no se borra. El nodo se encuentra en `g1` para más señas.

No termino de entender la complejidad que lleva asociada dicho destructor... si lo que pretendes es limpiar la memoria da exactamente igual si se quedan punteros inválidos a mitad de proceso... la gracia está en saber qué es lo que no hay que tocar durante el proceso de borrado... esos punteros se encuentran en elementos que van a ser borrados un instante más tarde, luego su estado temporal es irrelevante.

A mi se me ocurre un destructor más limpio tal que:

```
#include <set>

template <typename datonodo_t, typename datoarista_t>
Grafo<datonodo_t,datoarista_t>::~Grafo()
{
    std::cout<<"Iniciamos el destructor"<<std::endl;

    std::set<pArista> aristas;

    pNodo nodo = Raiz;
    while( nodo )
    {
      pArista arista = nodo->adyacente;
      while( arista )
      {
        aristas.insert(arista);
        arista = arista->siguiente;
      }

      pNodo temp = nodo->siguiente;
      delete nodo;
      nodo = temp;
    }

    for( pArista arista : aristas )
      delete arista;

    std::cout<<"Borrada la raiz"<<std::endl;
}
```

Seguramente con un diseño diferente de la clase `Grafo` se consiga un destructor más limpio... pero dado que desconozco los requisitos del proyecto se me hace un poco aventurado el proponer cambios más drásticos.

También, por legibilidad, te aconsejaría no usar alias para los punteros. Creo que es preferible que el asterisco aparezca siempre... así, por ejemplo se vería que una referencia constante a un puntero es algo absurdo ya que no aporta absolutamente nada salvo una indirección adicional.

Comment: Gracias @eferion. Brillante como siempre. De hecho ese es el enfoque que me gustaría haberle dado. No pensar en el grafo como tal, sino "atacar" a su representación (una lista de nodos del que pueden colgar una lista de aristas). De esta forma que planteas me puedo olvidar de ir recorriendo cada rama del grafo. Por otro lado, es verdad que en su momento planteé esto como una forma de aprender recursividad, por eso hay muchos métodos que funcionan así en el grafo.